# How to pass evaluated Eval in javascript function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, eval

I am very new in VB.NET, Can Evaluated Eval be passed as an argument to a javascript function? If so how I can do that? I need true or false in to be pass on javascript function

```
onclick='ShowViewPopup(this, "detail", null, null, <%#IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("CustomerNumber"))) %>';
```

Many Thanks

Comment: What do you want to have as a resulting argument in js? true/false? or the value that Eval outputs? your IIF is not complete

Comment: Hi, you could do the evalution in ShowViewPopup().

Comment: Hi, Andrei.. yes I need true or false in my output :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of `IIf`, you do not seem to need it. I also recommend output the whole function call with C# code, makes it easier on quotes. So (formatted for better readability):

```
onclick='<%#
    "ShowViewPopup(this, \"detail\", null, null, "
    + String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("CustomerNumber"))
    + ")"
%>'
```